# android json add hyperlink to text

Tags: java, android, json

Here is my json output sample:

```
{"podcast":[{"link":"rtsp:\\live.xxx.ro:554\vod\_definst_\mp4:05\rfm_00.mp4","name":"Recording 1"}
```

For parsing the json code i use this:

```
private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                            String link = c.getString(TAG_LINK);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_LINK, link);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                PodCast.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                        TAG_NAME, TAG_LINK },
                                new int[] { R.id.link, R.id.name });
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
```

For the layout this is the code of the link view:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorLink="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

All works well...but in the link view i get the whole link rtsp://live.xxx.ro...etc and i would like to be something like this:  `<a href="rtsp://...">NAME </a>` So i would have the name and when i click it to open the specified link.  Can you guys please help me figure it out how?

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

```
String href = String.format("<a href=\"%s\"> %s </a>", map.get(TAG_LINK), map.get(TAG_NAME));
textV.setText(Html.fromHTML(href))
```

Or if you have a link as a resource string; just make sure that the reserved HTML characters aren't converted to HTML entities.

An example that would parse incorrectly:

```
<string name="a_link">&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;click here&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

To fix it, edit `strings.xml` manually and convert HTML entities to characters they represent, 
so that the above becomes:

```
<string name="a_link"><a href="http://www.google.com">click here</a></string>
```

And it should work.

Comment: for more reference, here is the list of html tags which is supported in textview. http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: ok but how can i hide the <a></a> tags? I only want the Name to appear and when i click on it to open the specific link. Right now i have the whole code: <a href="link"> Name </a>

Comment: I want to ask the same question as @gogu . to show only the name and then when clicked, it redirects to the browser

Comment: @silentbang I updated my answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: @iccthedral I've found another solution which matchs my situation (with TextView inside ListView). should you check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a function setOnItemClickListener() and inside it declare something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
```